# Executing an Oracle Stored Proc as Another User

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, schema, oracle11g

I'm mostly an oracle novice, so forgive me if this is a stupid question...

I have a schema called 'CODE' with a stored proc that executes arbitrary SQL (for now, please ignore the potential security issues associated with that).  The SQL that is passed in will select data; but all of the data resides in either schema A, B, or C - but the SQL will only ever select from ONE schema at a time.

For example:  User of type A creates a string 'SELECT * FROM A.USERTABLE' - while user of type B creates a string 'SELECT * FROM B.USERTABLE'.

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to not explicitly specify their schema.  In the front-end .net application; I already know if they are type A, B, or C.  I want all three to simply enter 'SELECT * FROM USERTABLE'.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to do that.  My app can only execute proc in the 'CODE' schema - so I can't just duplicate the code and let user A call 'A.ExecuteSQL'.

I've tried a few things; but nothing has worked thus far.  I want the ExecuteSQL proc to stay in the CODE schema; but when 'USERTABLE' gets passed in, I need it to know that sometimes that means A.USERNAME and sometimes B.USERNAME.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = schema
```

That is the [equivalent to SQL Server's `EXECUTE AS` syntax](http://ss64.com/sql/executeas.html).

Comment: How does this works? First application executes this `ALTER` statement or execute this in procedure `CODE`?

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:588045400346317188 has some more info.  It looks like you can do it with dynamic sql (execute immediate) inside your stored proc.

Comment: @Guru: See Rob P's AskTom link

Comment: Thanks OMG. It should work. I know you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` within PL/SQL. But was skeptic, how this will change when it started executing and change to another schema in middle of that. Have to check them out.

Answer (score 9):

Another option would be using the AUTHID CURRENT_USER pragma.

If you add these two keywords immediately after your package, procedure, function or type name, it will execute with the privileges of the executing user, rather than the CODE schema. This overrides the default behaviour which is AUTHID DEFINER (the privileges of the schema/user that compiled the code)

i.e.

```
CREATE FUNCTION examplefunc
    (pSqlStatement IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN INTEGER
  AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS 
   lResult INTEGER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE pSqlStatement INTO lResult;
    RETURN lResult;
END examplefunc;
```

Note that for functions and procedures insider a package, the pragma can only be applied at the package level. You cannot set the rights on a per function basis.

This should cause any SQL inside the function, package, etc, to execute with the users privileges.

I've used that to manage a similar 'run any old bit of SQL dynamically' routine - at the very least you will have stopped a 'normal' user from being able to use your stored procedure to drop a table or install additional code in the CODE schema.

(It may also be worth - if you haven't already - adding some validation to throw out certain keywords - i.e. must start with SELECT, must not contain embedded pl/sql blocks - whatever you can get away with without breaking existing code).