# Can only one procedure within a PL/SQL package be run with AUTHID CURRENT_USER?

Tags: oracle, security, plsql

I have a PL/SQL package that does *not* specify an `AUTHID` (effectively making it `AUTHID DEFINER`). However, there is precisely one procedure within this package that needs to run as `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`. Is this possible, or must I create a separate, top-level procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure a new package would be needed since the AUTHID can only be specified at the PACKAGE level (to the best of my knowledge anyway)

Comment: Do you know of any documentation that confirms this?

Comment: @Adam, Your best bet is to test it on your DEV system. Then you'll know for sure for your DB version etc.

Comment: Write authid current_user at package **specification** CREATE PACKAGE package_name **AUTHID CURRENT_USER**
IS

Answer (score 2):

Though this linked question is slightly off-topic, the answer supplied by JulesLt explains that you can't specify AUTHID in a package at a level below the package level:

[Executing an Oracle Stored Proc as Another User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376664/executing-an-oracle-stored-proc-as-another-user)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution might be following:

1. You create a package with `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` option;
2. You grant select, insert, etc. to the objects that reside in the **DEFINER** schema that you want to use;
3. You use **fully qualified names** of the DEFINER objects.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE PACKAGE pkg1 AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
  procedure insert_current_user;
  procedure insert_definer;
END pkg1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg1
IS
  procedure insert_current_user
  is
  begin
    insert into table1 values(1);
  end insert_current_user;

  procedure insert_definer
  is
  begin
    insert into DEFINER.table1 values(1);
  end insert_definer;
END pkg1;
/
```

**DEFINER** is the owner of the table.

*As an improvement*, you can create a synonym for the `DEFINER.table1` table and then use the synonyms in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not allow the authid clause on a subprogram in a package or type. You will get the following error:

```
Error: PLS-00157: AUTHID only allowed on schema-level programs
```