# In ORACLE DB, determine if another user can run a select query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Is it possible to check whether another ORACLE user will be able to run a particular query? This check would need to be performed by an ADMIN account.

The reason for this is that we have processes that run using the ADMIN account. It's possible for non-admins to submit queries to these processes, so we want to be able to confirm during the execution of the process whether the user would be able to run the query themselves, and if not, end execution.

The other piece to this is that the process are controlled by a Java program, so if there is no way to do this in Oracle, perhaps there is a solution in Java/JDBC?

Java:1.5
Oracle: 10.2+
All the tables involved are part of the ADMIN schema, and access is controlled via SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE table GRANTS.

Hope I've been clear enough

Comment: maybe I'm oversimplifying, but wouldn't you just need more than 1 ADMIN connection to the db? (connect as ADMIN if the user is an admin, else connect as a less powerful user, NON_ADMIN or whatever).

Comment: Proxy authentication might be something to try out.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name great suggestion, thank you.  BTW, the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#i1007535) on proxy authentication, interesting read.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the undocumented Oracle package, DBMS_SYS_SQL, which has a `parse()` method that takes a user ID as a parameter. Here is a link with some info: http://www.pythian.com/blog/using-dbms_sys_sql-to-execute-statements-as-another-user/

Comment: This is an interesting approach, thanks for pointing it out. However, after reading through, the complexity and fact that this could break at any time means it's not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the solution is something called `execute as login`.  Given this information, I found that Oracle has the equivalent ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376664/executing-an-oracle-stored-proc-as-another-user) is a StackOverflow reference):

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = schema;
```

My suggestion is that before running the query, set the schema to the actual user.  Then, just let the query fail and return that error back to the calling program.

The Oracle documentation for this is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general009.htm).

EDIT:

The documentation for Oracle explicitly gives this example:

> CONNECT scott ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = joe; SELECT * FROM
>   emp;
>
> Because emp is not schema-qualified, the table name is resolved under
>   schema joe. But if scott does not have select privilege on table
>   joe.emp, then scott cannot execute the SELECT statement.

That gives me the impression that it is changing privileges when changing the schema.

Comment: Setting the current schema is something different than "execute as login". It merely changes the "default schema name" it does not change the current user (=login)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I freely admit to not having used this in Oracle.  However, the documentation suggests that the privileges are changing too.

Comment: The *visibility* of objects is changing, but not the priviletes, from the link you posted: "*The session **retains its original privileges** and does not acquire any extra privileges*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Yea, I tried this approach, but like I mentioned, since all the required tables are part of the ADMIN schema, changing the schema doesn't help much for me